# Лишние символы при чтении файла

Tags: c++, файлы, символы

Я написал простой код чтения с файла:

```
FILE *F, *G;
F = fopen("input.txt", "rb");
G = freopen("output.txt", "wb", stdout);

unsigned char c;
while(fscanf(F, "%c", &c) == 1) {
    cout << c << '\n';
}
```

Но по какой-то причине, когда я читаю файл с символовами

> ¼f6~

То код первым читает символ Â, которого даже нет в исходной строке. Откуда берётся этот символ?

Comment: imho ваш файл в многобайтной кодировке (например, utf8)

Comment: Кодировка, кодировка...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Символ `"¼"` представляется в кодировке `UTF-8` двумя байтами: `0xC2 0xBC`. Если ваш файл записан в кодировке `UTF-8`, то при чтении его в режиме `"rb"` (читать как двоичный файл) вы получите два байта подряд.

Когда вы читаете файл посимвольно и пытаетесь интерпретировать каждый байт как отдельный символ, то первый байт `"¼"` (`0xC2`) интерпретируется как символ `"Â"` в кодировке `Windows-1252` или в некоторых других однобайтовых кодировках, поскольку `0xC2` в этих кодировках соответствует символу `"Â"`.

Чтобы такого не происходило, вам нужно правильно обрабатывать многобайтовые символы (например, используя кодировку `UTF-8`) или убедиться, что файл, который вы читаете, сохранён в однобайтовой кодировке, например в `Windows-1252`, где каждый символ соответствует ровно одному байту.

Если вы хотите работать с текстом в кодировке `UTF-8` и правильно его отображать, вам придётся использовать другие функции, которые могут работать с `UTF-8`. В стандартной библиотеке `C++` для работы с `UTF-8` обычно используют библиотеки сторонних разработчиков, так как стандартная библиотека `C++` до `C++20` не имела встроенных средств для работы с этой кодировкой.

Также, обратите внимание, что вы используете функцию `"fscanf"` для ввода и смешиваете вызовы функций стандартной библиотеки `C` `(stdio.h)` и `C++` `(iostream)`. Это может вызвать проблемы с буферизацией вывода, поскольку `"cout"` из `C++` буферизируется отдельно от `"stdout"` из `C`.